# wordpress profile form in front in a page?

Tags: wordpress, profile

Is there a way to insert wordpress current login user's

E-mail*

Password*

Repeat Password*

Update

to a page?
And place the position like this?
[here is the example](http://pasteboard.co/1Th0NV1D.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean login or register?

Comment: I mean a user was login,then in a page,place those form can let user change it.

Answer (score 0):

yes, 
you can use wp_update_user() function
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user